# Can different nodes of same service act as consumer and producer?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have deployed my service on three different node.

I have a scenario where a user does some update (eg add new menu) which will go to nosql db(mongo).

I want to use Kafka so that one node will produce the event(new items added to menu) and all other node will consume .

The difficulty which I have is all nodes are running same service.

How can one act as a producer and others as consumer in Kafka?

Comment: And what would you do if the producer node dies?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.

You can use multiple producers per service, in this case, every pod (instance of your service) can send messages to a topic. Also, you can have multiple consumers per topic but only one consumer per partition in the same consumer group.

If you want to every consumer receive every message you can use different consumer group for all consumers.

If you want to receive one message only by one consumer you can use the same consumer group for all consumers.

The consumer can consume messages from multiple partitions, but only one consumer can consume messages from one partition.